# ISBLANK not working properly in formula field in auto-launched Flow?

Tags: formula, process-builder, visual-workflow, isblank

We have an auto-launched Flow that is called by a process builder.  The PB passes in some record values into flow variables.  We have a formula in the flow that uses `ISBLANK` to check these variables for null.

We've found that `ISBLANK` doesn't work.  In this formula, `campFirstName` is the text variable passed in from the PB, and `theContact` is a record variable (retrieved with a Get Records action).

```
IF(ISBLANK({!campFirstName}), {!theContact.FirstName}, {!campFirstName})
```

When `campFirstName` is null from the process builder, the formula still returns `{!campFirstName}` value instead of `theContact` value.

If we run the PB in debug mode, then it does work.  I guess that means debug mode is passing a true null instead of an empty string.

If we change the formula to this:

```
IF(OR(ISBLANK({!campFirstName}), {!campFirstName} = ""), {!theContact.FirstName}, {!campFirstName})
```

Then the formula works correctly and returns theContact value when campFirstName is null.

Has anyone else seen this?  I've searched around but can't find if this is a known issue and/or if it will be changed in Summer 20.

Comment: so, you are implying that the value of `campFirstName` on the Process Builder side is an empty string? but in the database it is null?  Have you tried passing the campaignId from PB to Flow and let Flow refetch the record?

Comment: Can you review this KI link? (https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003gv2QAA) and use ISNULL. instead of ISBLANK.

Comment: Yes, campFirstName is actually from a custom object but the field is definitely null.  We haven't tried doing a GetRecord on the custom object yet, we'll probably adjust the formulas to check empty string instead.  We're not getting the error in the Known Issue, it just doesn't work correctly.